# I want to refresh the react page(functional component) only once when it first loads, not on any event but after first render, how to do that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, reload

I am trying to refresh/reload an page in a react functional component. But when i call

> window.location.reload()

in useEffect() hook, the page keeps refreshing forever. I want it to refresh only once after it mounts.
How to achieve that?
So far I tried this:

```
useEffect(
    () => {
        setNotificationCount();
        window.location.reload();
    },[]
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can store a flag inside the `localStorage`:

```js
useEffect(
    () => {
        setNotificationCount();
        const alreadyLoaded = localStorage.getItem('alreadyLoaded');
        if (!alreadyLoaded) {
           localStorage.setItem('alreadyLoaded', true);
           window.location.reload();
        }
    },[]
)
```

Comment: What a brilliant idea!

Comment: I tried but for some reason it didn't work...

Comment: What is `setNotificationCount` doing?

Comment: It shows the notification count.